# how to display upload or default logo in redux framework option

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework

I am using Redux Framework for Wordpress theme. Then upload logo from redux options panel.

### here is my redux option code :

```
array(
    'id'        => 'opt_header_logo',
    'type'      => 'media',
    'url'       => true,
    'title'     => __('Logo', 'demo' ),
    'compiler'  => 'false',
    'subtitle'  => __('Upload your logo', 'demo' ),
    'default'   => array('url' => IMAGES . '/logo.png'),
),
```

### here is my display code :

```
<?php if($redux_demo['opt_header_logo']['url']!='') { ?>
    <img alt="" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png">
<?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php global $redux_demo; echo''.$redux_demo['opt_header_logo']['url']; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

i want to display default image if image is not uploaded. this code is display uploaded image perfectly but when i delete uploaded image from redux option default image is not showing.

Please help ?

Thanks

Comment: Your iif statement makes no sense. If  the  `redux_demo['opt_header_logo']['url']` is _not_ empty, you're using the default, if it _is_ empty, you're using its value (which you just confirmed is empty!). It's backwards. Another thing, if you need to use global for that variable (which I don't think you do), you need to have that _before_ your if-statement, or that it will fail.

Comment: sorry to say ! but i m not expert i am just beginner  that is why i came here for solution @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok finally i got the answer and my code is working fine.

### here is my output working code:

```
                    <?php global $redux_demo; if($redux_demo['opt_header_logo']['url']!='') { ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $redux_demo['opt_header_logo']['url']; ?>">
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <img alt="" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png">
                    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

URL value is boolean in your array so you should check true or false 
Try this..

```
if($redux_demo['opt_header_logo']['url']) {} else {}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: There are plenty of more errors in the OP's small if statement. Just sayin'

Comment: no its not working. its working fine when logo upload but when i remove uploaded image and save the setting default image is not showing @ShefaliPrajapati

Comment: try  if (isset($redux_frame['logo']['url']))  @gulrathod

Comment: no still its now showing default image when i delete upload logo  @Shefali Prajapati

Answer (score 0):

Or just simply replace IMAGES with your stylesheet directory uri and make sure you have the default image inside your theme directory

```
array(
    'id'        => 'opt_header_logo',
    'type'      => 'media',
    'url'       => true,
    'title'     => __('Logo', 'demo' ),
    'compiler'  => 'false',
    'subtitle'  => __('Upload your logo', 'demo' ),
    'default'   => array('url' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/logo.png'),
),
```

then echo the field

`<?php echo $redux_demo['opt_header_logo']['url'] ?>` cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
array(
    'id'        => 'opt_header_logo',
    'type'      => 'media',
    'url'       => true,
    'title'     => __('Logo', 'demo' ),
    'compiler'  => 'false',
    'subtitle'  => __('Upload your logo', 'demo' ),
    'default'   => array('url' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/logo.png'),
),

<?php echo $redux_demo['opt_header_logo']['url'] ?>
```